# I need to show error when user presses escape on prompt box , but code below doesnt seem to work, any answers?

Tags: javascript

```
function(catchError) {
    try {

       var firstname = prompt("please enter your first name");

}

    catch (error) {

       alert(error.message);

}}
```

1. how can I remove this problem

2 also make this work in google chrome

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` will return `null` if cancel or the escape key is pressed. Just check for it:

```
var firstname = prompt("please enter your first name");
if(firstname !== null) {

} else {
    // ESC or cancel pressed
}
```

Comment: I have already done that but I need to make it work by this method , some issue I am having

Comment: Make it work how? You can not magically make it go into the catch. If you want it to go in to the catch, you need to add the check and throw one yourself.

Comment: can you show it to me in a comment or by giving an answer, I am new to javascript ? Thanx